# SQL query results from one table, where certain values exist in a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres 11 and trying to fetch all columns from table `cmdb_mgmt`, matching both tables against column `hostname` (fkey), where in table `config_data.interface` column `last_seen` is `null`. This is query I have, which runs but returns no results:

```
select
    *
from
    cmdb_mgmt, config_data.interface
where
    config_data.interface.last_seen in (
        select config_data.interface.last_seen from config_data.interface where config_data.interface.last_seen is null
);
```

A potential caveat is that the same values for `hostname` exist numerous times in `config_data.interface` due to `hostname` being one part of a composite pkey. They exist only once in `cmdb_mgmt` however.

Comment: Do you have a question?  If so, illustrating your question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would help.

Comment: what about a simple join?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka a join would include columns from my second table. I only want columns from the first table as part of the result set. I was able to find a working query.

Comment: SELECT cmdb_mgmt.*    ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might want to do this, instead:

```
SELECT cmdb_mgmt.*
  FROM cmdb_mgmt
 WHERE cmdb_mgmt.hostname IN (
        SELECT config_data.interface.hostname
          FROM config_data.interface
         WHERE config_data.interface.last_seen IS NULL
);
```

Your version had an accidental CROSS JOIN / cartesian product.

Comment: Why not a simple inner join? Run the query analyzer on both version and see what u get

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka That could return different results if hostname is not unique in the interface table.  We would need DISTINCT to handle that issue.

Comment: yes - run analyzer to see which is better. Usually inner queries are not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the results I need by using this query. I had some simple syntax issues.

```
select
    cmdb_mgmt.*
from
    cmdb_mgmt, config_data.interface
where
    cmdb_mgmt.hostname in (
        select config_data.interface.hostname from config_data.interface where config_data.interface.last_seen is null
);
```

Comment: Remove , config_data.interface from the fourth line - u r doing a cartezic multiplication.